# vows unit test got executed multiple times when the included app server uses nodejs cluster.fork

Tags: node.js, vows

My app server uses node.js cluster API cluster.fork() to fork multiple child processes. This works fine.

However, when I try to use vows for unit test, the test also got run multiple times because of the call to cluster.fork() inside my app server; as I instantiate the server inside my test code, as follows:

basic-test.js

```
var vows = require('vows');
var MyAppServer = require('../my_app');

// start the server 
var app = MyAppServer.start();    

var suite = vows.describe('My Tests');
suite.discuss('connections API')
    .addBatch({ ... })
    .export(module);
```

How do I prevent test code to run multiple times in this case ? This test is included in npm test, so I need a way to instantiate my app server inside test itself.

Answer (score 1):

At the top you can do

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
```

Then wrap the suite in an `if`:

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    var suite = ...
    ...
}
```

For more info on `isMaster`, check [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_ismaster)

Comment: Thanks, That's what I have done after posting the question. However, tehre are two issues, first, the worker will emit out no 'Could not find any tests to run', because it started but nothing to test. I tried to stuff dummy tests there, no working. The second problems is, my server is running inside worker. The vows test running inside master will started immediately while the forked server in worker is not ready, hence all tests failed.